# Angular NumberValueAccessor form control value changes subscribed twice

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, subscription, form-control

Hi there I am experiencing a really weird issue, formgroup value changes subscribed twice for a single change.
Here are some code snippets which describes what I am trying to do. Unfortunately not able to create an stackblitz at the moment due some connectivity.
numbers-only-input component html file

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="bsl-form-field-input">
  <mat-label>{{ matLabel }}</mat-label>
  <input
    type="number"
    matInput
    [placeholder]="placeHolder"
    [formControl]="formControl"
    autocomplete="off"
    appNumbersOnly
  />
</mat-form-field>
```

numbers-only-input component ts file

```
import { Component, Input, OnDestroy, OnInit, forwardRef } from '@angular/core';
import {
  FormControl,
  NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
  NumberValueAccessor,
} from '@angular/forms';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-numbers-only-input',
  templateUrl: './numbers-only-input.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./numbers-only-input.component.scss'],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => NumbersOnlyInputComponent),
      multi: true,
    },
  ],
})
export class NumbersOnlyInputComponent
  extends NumberValueAccessor
  implements OnDestroy, OnInit
{
  @Input()
  formControl: FormControl;
  @Input()
  matLabel: string;
  @Input()
  placeHolder: string;

  destroySubject = new Subject<void>();


  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.destroySubject.next();
    this.destroySubject.complete();
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.formControl.valueChanges.subscribe(value=>console.log(value))
  }
}
```

numbers only directive file which is just preventing to enter any character except number and allowing paste values only for valid numbers.

```
import { Directive, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appNumbersOnly]',
})
export class NumbersOnlyDirective {
  regEx = '^[0-9]+$';

  // only numbers are allowed
  @HostListener('keypress', ['$event'])
  onKeyPress(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    return new RegExp(this.regEx).test(event.key);
  }

  // block paste for non numeric values
  @HostListener('paste', ['$event'])
  onPaste(event: ClipboardEvent) {
    const pastedString = event?.clipboardData?.getData('text/plain');
    if (pastedString && !Number.isNaN(+pastedString)) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

anyone please help me to resolve this. here is my console
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use rxjs to reduce the number of calls. By taking the unique values and excluding multiple emissions through `throttleTime`. Please find below a working example!

If this does not work please replicate the issue in the below stackblitz and share back!

```
   ngOnInit(): void {
    this.formControl.valueChanges
      .pipe(
        distinctUntilChanged(),
        throttleTime(500),
        takeUntil(this.destroySubject)
      )
      .subscribe((value) => console.log(value));
  }
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-dczfmb)

Comment: Thanks @Naren Murali, I was verifying on other scenarios and it is working fine till now.